# Tomcat or Spring Suite Tool's default server does not run in Simple Spring Web Maven project

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I created a simple Spring -> Simple Spring Web Maven Project using Spring Tool Suite. I created controller and view etc. There are already web.xml. Besides, when I create Spring MVC Project it does work but there are problems when I add some codes that I know it works (Examples from Spring in Action, particularly Spitter example). So, I think there are other problems related with Spring MVC project but still I think tomcat 7 should be able to see this project as a runnable project.

Also, I looked at recommendation posts and nearly 10 15 posts but I cannot find the correct answer for this silly problem.

Thanks in advance. I appreciate any useful comments.

Here is a picture of what I've faced:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the right facets are set:

Right click project name -> properties -> project facets:

- Dynamic Web Project
- Servlet 3

**Update**

To declare a specific Java version in your maven project add these settings to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
 ...

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
       <source>1.6</source>
       <target>1.6</target>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>

 <plugins>
<build>
```

Comment: none of them has checked but when I try to check it, it says "dynamic web module 3.0 requires Java 1.6 or newer". But I'm already using Java 1.7

Comment: Is the Java facet checked as well and does it say: Java 1.6? If not see my updated answer.

Comment: I said none of them checked but I first tried to check Java than I tried to check dynamic web project. So, it did not bring what I expect but I could see the run on server part. Thanks for your help I appreciate your answer :)